# Prevent GNU screen from terminating session once executed script ends

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm trying to force GNU screen to create a "virtual" terminal, without attaching to it, execute script inside and NOT terminate session once script ends.

I tried many combinations, including:

```
screen -dmS udplistener /share/Sys/autorun/start_udp_listeners.sh
```

or

```
screen -S udplistener -X /share/Sys/autorun/start_udp_listeners.sh
```

and none of them worked. I either get session without executed script, script executes, but session is terminated once it finishes or I'm getting "No screen session found" error.

What I'm basically trying to do is to run UDP listener, written in PHP and make it work in infinte loop (don't break listening). Yes -- I could run PHP script with `&` at the end, forcing PHP CLI to run as daemon. The problem is, that I'm using a piece of junk called server (QNAP -- never, ever buy this junk!) which does seems to be ignoring this. As soon as I logoff SSH session, scripts stops.

So `screen` seems to be the only option. But I can't understand, why it terminates session once executed command or script ends?

**EDIT**: I've also tried example found in the Internet:

```
screen -dmS name
screen -S name -p windowname -X stuff 'mc
'
```

No lack! After attaching to it (`screen -R name`) I see that Midnight Commander HASN'T been executed. Though example author said, it will be.

Comment: The way you are invoking `screen`, you only create one window to run a single command.  When the command exits, the window closes and `screen` has nothing left to do, so it exits.

Comment: So... is there a way to open two windows (using command line only, no keyboard combinations), one to execute a script and second to prevent `screen` from closing? BTW: I still don't get the idea behind! If I call `screen -dmS name`, I create a detached window, which also has nothing left to do. But it isn't automatically closed! But when I want to execute something in that detached screen, it ends once execution is done. Why? I don't see logic here. Can have window doing nothing, but can't have window doing something and then doing nothing?

Comment: When you start a window without specifying a command, it is *not* "doing nothing".  The "something" it is doing is running an interactive shell, which does not exit until you exit it manually.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for an explanation! So... back to the question... is there any way to run a command inside a detached screen/window and NOT to end that session, once command execution ends? Also, please take a look at updated question. Thank you.

Comment: This script is executing two UDP listeners written in PHP. Though both are executed as daemons (with `&` at the end), due to buggy server (QNAP), they're are terminated when session ends (I was told, they shouldn't on normal Linux, if executed with `&`). So I'm not looking to do anything after `start_udp_listeners.sh` finishes, only how to prevent session from being terminated. As long as it isn't, my PHP listeners are working just fine.

Comment: One way to see what was on the screen is to use Logfile: 

" -L   tells screen to turn on automatic output logging for the windows. "

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To keep screen busy after the script completes, just keep something persistent running in a window.  The simplest choice for that "something" is probably an interactive shell.  Here's one way to do it (assuming `bash` as the choice of interactive shell):

```
screen -dmS session_name sh -c '/share/Sys/autorun/start_udp_listeners.sh; exec bash'
```

- `-dm`: starts screen in detached mode
- `-S`: sets session name for screen for easier retrieval later on
- `sh -c '...'`: instead of simply running your script, which will terminate, use `sh -c` to run multiple commands
- `exec bash`: after the script terminates, the `sh` from above will switch over to an interactive shell (`bash`), which should never exit until something external terminates it.  This will keep `screen` open as long as the `bash` instance is alive.

Comment: Hm... seems you're my life saviour! :] Extending your solution with `export IGNOREEOF=1` to prevent accidential termination with Ctrl+D should give me the perfect solution, I've been looking whole long evening. THANKS! :]

Comment: This doesn't work on Debian as of today, -c is an argument to read an alternative .screenrc file...

Comment: @ToVine works perfectly on Debian Stable (Wheezy). I used `bash -c` though.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud did you enclose the whole command "bash -c ..." in quotes? The last time I tried it (right before writing the comment) it didn't work for me, not quite sure why...

Comment: @ToVine here is my whole command: `screen -LS sauf bash -c "sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude full-upgrade; exec bash"`

Comment: Thanks!  In Arch Linux with an Anaconda Python 3.5 virtual environment ("py35") established, this line in my ~/.screenrc file starts a persistent window named `Py3` running that Python 3.5 venv:

screen -t Py3 bash -c "source activate py35 && python; exec bash"

Comment: but we loose the stdout and the command history(to run it manually using up arrow)... looking at the window, it's like the command has never been launched in this window. Why can't we get the same behavior as manually creating a window with `Ctrl-a c`?!

Answer (score 2):

I had no luck with `sh -c` on my raspberry pi 2 running Debian 7.8. But `bash -c` did the job:

**Command:**

```
/usr/bin/screen -dmS test-screen bash -c "/usr/bin/top; exec bash"
```

Comment: Could this be, because you're using (on Raspberry Pi) a different shell? The `bash` and `sh` seems to be two different shells. That's all, I think, but I may be wrong, since I'm newbie to Linux at all.

Comment: sh is the default unix-shell, it is included in raspbian (debian). The command sh also works, but not sh -c in combination with screen.

Comment: Thank you @scotty86, I observed the same in Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04) and changing `sh -c` to `bash -c` did the trick. I don't understand why, both `sh` and `bash` are installed,  so I'm still losing sleep over it, but at least it works.

Comment: `sh` probably points to `/bin/dash` instead of `/bin/bash`. Debian switched the default shell from `bash` to  `dash` a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

My motivation not terminating the session was to not loose the outputs of the session. In this context the linux tool `script` came to my mind.

```
rm script_session.log
script -e -f -a script_session.log -c "screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200"
```

If the serial USB adapter is unplugged the session is terminated but I still can read the output from `script_session.log`. However not with `cat` since the escape sequences contained in 'script_session.log' make the output disappear from the terminal. You can use e.g `gedit` or `vi` or a tool that strips escape sequences from a file.

Maybe `script` could be useful also for detached `screen` session.