# Running `screen` through a @reboot cron job

Tags: cron, gnu-screen

I want to have a script running in screen at startup.

This doesn't work:

```
@reboot pi screen -d -m /home/pi/db_update.py
```

however running this manually as user pi works:

```
screen -d -m /home/pi/db_update.py
```

Any idea on what I am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of adding `@reboot pi ...` to `/etc/crontab` you should run `crontab -e` as user `pi` and add:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/screen -d -m /home/pi/db_update.py
```

Make sure to use the full path to screen (just to be sure, it works without it), and that the /home/pi is not on an encrypted filesystem (been there, done that). The command cannot depend on anything that might only be accessible after either the `cron` daemon has started, or the user is logged in.

You might want to add something to `db_update.py` (writing to a file in `/var/tmp` to see that it actually runs, or put a time.sleep(600) at the end of the python program to allow enough time to login and connect.

---

Tested on Lubuntu 13.04, python 2.7.4 with the following entry:

```
@reboot screen -d -m /home/anthon/countdown.py
```

and the `countdown.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
for x in range(600,0,-1):
    print x
    time.sleep(1)
```

(and `chmod 755 countdown.py`)

Comment: I'll try that out in a few minutes!

Comment: Still its not running ... There is no error message or anything in syslog, so im not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: I ran a screen from my crontab using `28 15 * * * screen -d -m find /` that does work, will try to run on reboot as well. Stupid question: are you sure cron is running and can find the screen binary?

Comment: its not throwing any error - in syslog I can see the cron calling the script as user pi on startup

Comment: `Jun  3 14:28:37 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[1987]: (pi) CMD (screen -d -m /home/pi/dbpdate.py)`  Spotted a Typo! :) Ill try again right now

Comment: Finally got it to work (first used an encrypted home dir on the VM that I was testing on). The difference was in specifying the full path to `/usr/bin/screen`. I will update the answer.

Comment: I have /usr/bin in my path - so it should work without it. However I added it like you suggest but its still not working:
`Jun  3 16:55:30 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[1969]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/screen -d -m /home/pi/db_update.py)`

Comment: Are you sure it is not db_update.py quitting because it depends on something? I included my test program, maybe you can try that.

Comment: Ill test it in a bit - need to do some work then ill be back here tonight - thanks for the continuous help!

Comment: Had not much time because of work - still had no success in running the screen session on startup, even with the script workaround. I'll keep trying - its probably something rather stupid I'm not seeing..

Comment: I just redid everything - I probably had some access rights not set properly - now it works! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar but slightly different use scenario for needing screen attached to something on startup. I have two headless servers, one of which has serial-only output. I have this attached to the other headless server via serial cable and I needed to use screen to interact via the serial connection. I also need to make sure I've captured any output generated while not viewing the serial session.

I have this in root's crontab

```
@reboot    /usr/bin/screen -d -m -c .screenrc -L /dev/ttyS0
```

The server reboots at a set time of day if security updates have been applied. I want specifically named log files so I can review them if need be. My `.screenrc` file has this entry in it

```
logfile "/root/.screen_%H_%Y%m%d_%c.txt"
```

so when the next screen session is started, the log file is at `/home/root/.screen_$HOSTNAME_$YYYYMMDD_$h:$mm.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

While this may be a workaround, I have overcome this issue by running a shell script which invokes my screen session.

```
[dude@server ~]$ crontab -l | grep sh
@reboot /home/dude/.autoscreen/start.sh
[dude@server ~]$ cat /home/dude/.autoscreen/start.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd ~
screen -S myname -d -m custom_script
```

Comment: Any ideas why doing this makes a difference (besides changing the cwd)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few simple ways to figure what is going on with that screen started upon boot:

- does it even start? after reboot, `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` should return a `CMD` line for it after the line saying `(CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)`
- if it starts, but the screen is gone by the time you look, then the command within exited - there's several ways to debug this, for example:

  - run a shell afterwards so it continues running and you can examine the output, as explained at e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47279/103306 - `screen ... -- sh -c "your command; exec sh"`
  - run the command within script(1), e.g. `screen ... -- script -f yourcommand.boot.log -c "your command"` and then examine the log file

In my case, it was a script that tried to connect to the local PostgreSQL database, which wasn't done booting, and it croaked with a `FATAL` error message. That is, everything was fine with `cron` and `screen` as such, but the combination simply ran too soon in the machine boot-up sequence.

Also, I should mention that you don't have to necessarily switch from global crontab file (`/etc/crontab`) to the user file, there's a middle ground in creating e.g. `/etc/cron/local-pi-whathaveyou` with your command. That way it's obvious to anyone who examines `/etc`, but you keep your unprivileged user.