# Is there a way to run a program at startup and in the background without root access?

Tags: root, startup, services, background-process

I'm trying to have it so that my program is able to run at startup and in the background without having the user to be root. Ideally this would happen at the installation of the program and not using a script modification after the program has been installed.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: a `@reboot` cron job is one option https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78017/running-screen-through-a-reboot-cron-job but does require appropriate configuration of the crontab...

Comment: Background and foreground are concepts associated with login sessions and controlling terminals.  Do you mean in the background?  Or not associated with a login session and controlling terminal at all, where the concept of background does not apply?