# Maintain screen session when executing shell script on boot

Tags: bash, scripting, cron, gnu-screen

**Solved:**
I solved this problem by introducing a delay before executing the script: `@reboot sleep 60; /root/start_server.sh`

---

On Ubuntu 14.04, I have a crontab entry set to run on reboot:

```
@reboot /root/start_server.sh
```

And here's `start_server.sh`:

```
screen -dmS server bash -c "cd server ; ./run.sh"
```

When the system starts up, `run.sh` is indeed executed, and the server remains up, but there are no sessions when I type `screen -ls`. Because of this, I can't access my server process after boot.

What's happening to the session I named "server"? If it's being terminated somehow, how do I prevent that?

I've tried adding `exec bash` to `start_server.sh` as per the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47279/85439), but it had no effect.

Comment: Does `ps -A` show that `screen` is still running? Also, are you running `screen -ls` as the same user that `screen` originally starts as?

Comment: No, `ps -A` does not list `screen`. As for your second question, I'm unsure. I'm running `screen -ls` as root, and the job was assigned to root's crontab entry. That means `screen` starts under root, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe it will be running as root. The only possibility I can think of is that `run.sh` terminates, ending the screen session. If the server detaches from the starting terminal and goes into the background, then `run.sh` will terminate, even though the server keeps running.

Comment: Have you patched Bash for the shellshock vulnerability? That patch removes some of bash's ability to execute commands fed to it on stdin as the `screen` may be doing. Try it with the old, unpatched version of bash that was on your system. That would be the quickest way to rule that out.

Comment: try run `sudo screen -ls` it appeared that screen is shown only for user by whom it was created